# Generate multiple buttons to Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm doing an ASP.Net MVC 5 web aplication. One of the pages is a Statistics page, that is suppose to have a SelectList, to select how much Charts I have on this page (1, 2, 4 or 6).
Then I'll have the same amount of buttons to generate individually each graphic

Like this:

```
<div id="myContainer">
  <select id="totalCharts>
     ....
  </select>
  <div id="ChartArea1">
      <button id="btn1"></button>
      <canvas id="chart1></canvas>
  </div>

    ....
  <div id="ChartAreaN">
     <button id="btnN"></button>
     <canvas id="chartN></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I want to generate each chart with an Ajax request upon the button clicked.

I tried several ways but non of them work. Could you tell the easiest way?

Comment: post what you have tried in your question please.

Comment: the code is a little big, but i managed to generate several charts with diferent id's like "chart1", "chart2", etc... the problem is when i wanna generate different AJAX requests with the same ID's

Comment: then isolate the relevant parts of the code and show us what you have done so far. aside of asking for the "easiest way"( which is a relevant term as something which is hard for one can be easy for another), your question is really unclear, opinion based, broad and shows no effort whatsoever. please post in your question a specific code that you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the link for complete code:
http://jsfiddle.net/hacker1211/n72vv902/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var n=10; //no of items in dropdown
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
                $('#totalCharts').append('<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>');
            }                   
        });     
        //code to populate divs,buttons,canvas
        $('#totalCharts').change(function(){
            for(j=1;j<=$(this).val();j++){
                $('#myContainer').append('<div id="ChartArea'+j+'"><button id="btn'+j+'">Button '+j+'</button><canvas id="chart'+j+'"> </canvas></div>');
            }
        });
        $('button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url="http://www.example.com"; //put your url here
            var id=$(this).attr('id'); //if you need button id
            $.ajax(url, {
                success: function(data) {
                    //code to draw chart here
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Error in sending ajax');
                }
            });

        });
```